# Adding Custom Marker to Gmap

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to add a cutom marker to this gmap;

```
$(function() {
    var addresspicker = $( "#addresspicker" ).addresspicker();
    var addresspickerMap = $( "#addresspicker_map" ).addresspicker(
    {
        regionBias: "au",
        map:      "#map_canvas",
        typeaheaddelay: 1000,
        mapOptions: {
            zoom:16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8674869, 151.2069902)
        }

    });

    addresspickerMap.on("addressChanged", function(evt, address) {
       console.dir(address);
    });
    addresspickerMap.on("positionChanged", function(evt, markerPosition) {
        markerPosition.getAddress( function(address) {
            if (address) {
                $( "#addresspicker_map").val(address.formatted_address);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

The marker is like:

http://oursite.com.au/includes/helper/images/422marker.png

width:33px by 50px

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
marker: 'http://oursite.com.au/includes/helper/images/422marker.png',
```

But that didnt work ... any ideas please

Comment: likely help to provide link to plugin you are using, I would imagine docs would outline custom markers. Google map API makes them fairly simple to create, but not sure how they get added to your plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker will be returned by `addresspickerMap.addresspicker( "marker")` , you may use the setIcon-method of the marker to apply a custom Icon:

```
addresspickerMap.addresspicker( "marker")
  .setIcon('http://oursite.com.au/includes/helper/images/422marker.png');
```